# Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'

Tags: flutter

return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
title: Text("Demo"),
),
body: Center(
child: FutureBuilder(
future: fetchphoto() ,
builder: (ctx, snapshot){

```
        if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }else{
          return ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder:(_, index){
              return ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: NetworkImage(snapshot.data[index]['thumbnailUrl'])),
                title: Text(snapshot.data[index]['title']),
                subtitle:Text("${snapshot.data[index]??['id']}"),
              );
            },
            itemCount: 12,
          );
        }
      },
    )
  ),
   // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
);
```

}
}**strong text**

Comment: Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
                    leading: CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: NetworkImage(snapshot.data[index]['thumbnailUrl'])),

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can work :

```dart
"${snapshot.data[index]??['id']}"),
```

Remove '??'

Comment: i removed this"??" also the program not work

Comment: share full code please